# Hide Rows Automatically via Cell Result Change

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub hide()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Ballast Quote")
    Set targetRange = ws.Range("A20:A30")

    targetRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    For Each c In targetRange.Rows
       If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(c, "<>0") - WorksheetFunction.CountIf(c, "") = 0) And (WorksheetFunction.CountA(c) - WorksheetFunction.Count(c) = 0) Then
           c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
       End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

This macro works perfectly but i would rather not have to go in and hit "F5" every time a range of cell changes.  My issue is that the cells that trigger the macro are not changed manually but are a result of another sheet, example cell A20 shows "=Inventory!$L$41".  I have not found any answers on this on options to have a button or if cell is changed manually.  Any takers???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Worksheet.Change Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) on your `inventory` worksheet to test if the original data changed:

```
'this must be in Inventory worksheet!
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("L41")) Is Nothing Then     
        hide 'run your procedure to hide
    End If
End Sub
```

This tests if `Inventory!$L$41` changed and if so it runs your hide procedure.

Comment: I have just inserted code for Inventory worksheet! and same issue occurs.  Cell value changes but rows remain unchanged??? This has been my dilemma.

Comment: either it is spelled wrong, or in the wrong module, workbook or worksheet file

Comment: This should definitely work if you change the value in L41 of the inventory sheet. Put a breakpoint in your code to see if it gets triggered. Then use F8 to go through it step by step.

Comment: Is it possible it does not work because L41 is also a formulated cell in the other sheet? cell shows as "=SUMIF(B7:B39,K11,C7:C39)"

Comment: of course this cannot work with formulas. You must trigger it on the original value (not formula) change. So change `Range("L41")` to `Range("B7:B39,K11,C7:C39")` in the code I provided.

Comment: SWEEEEEEEEEEEET!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: So far so good.  If i need to add another separate item such as =SUMIF(B7:B39,K9,C7:C39) which controls another row to also be hidden how would i input this in to code?

Comment: you just need to add `K9` since the other ranges are the same. So `Range("B7:B39,K11,C7:C39,K9")` should work.

Comment: Sorry i have foolishly solved my own question.  Thanks again PEH

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into Events, these are usually Sub or function called whenever something happens to a sheet/workbook

The particular event you want is: Worksheet.Change (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.change?view=vsto-2017)

Or Worksheet.Calculate (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.calculate?view=vsto-2017)

You can hook that sub to activate yours or enter your code in there. The documentation is in C# but uses the same Events, properties and methods

Comment: This does not work on formulas (OP has formulas) only if the value of the cell changes by user edit or VBA edit.

Comment: well you can also do the event of the data sheet and activate the hiding or showing on the result sheet. or you can use Worksheet.Calculate

Comment: I have tried some a couple "worksheet.Change" and calculation scenarios but nothing has worked.  I am pretty new to the VBA and have learnt a ton the last week or so.  Unfortunately i cannot call the macro above my own.  If you have an example i can paste in to "view code" that i can try that would be a good starting point.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JakeLenis if you put in a break does it then trigger?

Comment: i have inserted a break with no luck

Comment: If you follow this tutorial https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/events.html 
does that event work?